# Mock ServiceException in Graph API Calls as part of unit tests

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently mocking the Graph API calls as below in the unit tests. How can I simulate a ServiceException (`Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException`)?

```
        public static void SetupMockValues(Mock<IRequestAdapter> mockRequestAdapter, HostReputation host, string value)
        {
                mockRequestAdapter.Setup(
                adapter => adapter.SendAsync(It.Is<RequestInformation>(
                    ri => (string) ri.PathParameters["host%2Did"] == value
                ), Microsoft.Graph.Models.Security.HostReputation.CreateFromDiscriminatorValue, It.IsAny<Dictionary<string, ParsableFactory<IParsable>>>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
                ).ReturnsAsync(host);
            
        }
```

Comment: Which version of the SDK do you use?

Comment: @user2250152 I use 5.21.0